# Python - Add days to an existing date

Tags: python, class, methods, operator-overloading

Obviously this is homework so I can't import but I also don't expect to be spoon fed the answer. Just need some help on something that's probably pretty simple, but has had me stumped for too many hours now. I have to add days to an existing date in python. Here is my code:

```
class Date:
    """
    A class for establishing a date.
    """
    min_year = 1800

    def __init__(self, month = 1, day = 1, year = min_year):
        """
        Checks to see if the date is real.
        """
        self.themonth = month
        self.theday = day
        self.theyear = year
    def __repr__(self):
        """
        Returns the date.
        """
        return '%s/%s/%s' % (self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)

    def nextday(self):
        """
        Returns the date of the day after given date.
        """
        m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
        monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
        maxdays = monthdays[self.themonth]

        if self.theday != maxdays:
            return Date(self.themonth, self.theday+1, self.theyear)
        elif self.theday == maxdays and self.themonth == 12:
            return Date(1,1,self.theyear+1)
        elif self.theday == maxdays and self.themonth != 12:
            return Date(self.themonth+1, 1, self.theyear)

    def prevday(self):
        """
        Returns the date of the day before given date.
        """
        m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
        monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
        if self.theday == 1 and self.themonth == 1 and self.theyear == 1800:
            raise Exception("No previous date available.")
        if self.theday == 1 and self.themonth == 1 and self.theyear != 1800:
            return Date(12, monthdays[11], self.theyear-1)
        elif self.theday == 1 and self.themonth != 1:
            return Date(self.themonth -1, monthdays[self.themonth-1], self.theyear)
        elif self.theday != 1:
            return Date(self.themonth, self.theday - 1, self.theyear)

    def __add__(self, n):
        """
        Returns a new date after n days are added to given date.
        """
        for x in range(1, n+1):
            g = self.nextday()
        return g
```

But for some reason my `__add__` method won't run `nextday()` the right amount of times. Any suggestions?

Comment: How many times is it running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's running the correct number of times, but since `nextday` doesn't mutate a `date` object, you are just asking for the date after the current one over and over. Try:

```
def __add__(1, n):
    """
    Returns a new date after n days are added to given date.
    """
    g = self.nextday()
    for x in range(1, n):
        g = g.nextday()
    return g
```

With `g = self.nextday()`, you create a temporary object that is then incremented by repeatedly assigning itself to the following day. The range has to be changes to `range(1,n)` to compensate for the initial day, though I'd personally write it as `range(0,n-1)`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Good point; I usually still write it as I mentioned however because it reads better. *Range from 0 to n-1* rather than *Range to n-1*.